# Drupal 7 #ajax to set $_Session variable and redirect the page

Tags: ajax, session, drupal

I want that on click of a link in a form in drupal , the $_Session variable is set with some drop down value from the form A on Page A  and then redirect the page to another page B with Form B  which will show the drop down as prepopulated.

Is it possible with '#ajax' attribute for the page.?

If not #ajax how do i do that.? Can I use the hook_menu() and then have a  callback  function to set the $_Session variable and then redirect to another page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use a button instead of a link. That way you can use the usual form processing. Because you redirect the user anyway, Ajax is of no benefit here.

Comment: Thanks Oswald. User requirment to have 3 links for the form which will take them to different pages. How can I do that with a link? Can I have a hidden Submit button which will be used when ever a click happens? But problem with that if I want to open 3 links in separate browsers...

Comment: Use three buttons *instead of* three links. Why do you think you need hidden Submit buttons? If you want to open 3 links in separate browsers, you should put that into your qestion instead of talking about redirects.